# How to get two pieces of text to sit next to each other and be responsive to screen width changes?

Tags: html, css

[Website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ltnc.jpg)I'm trying to get these two pieces of text to sit next to each other rather than on top of each other. I also want them to be responsive to screen size adjustment.

'Carttext' is positioned where I want it on the screen when 'Icontext' is removed and is responsive to screen size adjustment.

I want 'Icontext' to sit just to the left of it but I can't seem to achieve this with it still being responsive to screen size changes. Any tips would be much appreciated, Code is below.

```html
<div id="Icontext";
style="position: relative;">Login</DIV>
                 
<div id="Carttext";
style="position: relative;">Cart</DIV>
```

Comment: You have a spurious `;` there in the middle of everything. Did you try any CSS? For example `float:left` or `display:inline-block` might be useful - also try using `<span...>`

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline-block`?

Comment: Which is the spurious ; ? I  have tried lots of different things including adding various CSS. I think my lack of knowledge is letting me down though

Comment: @AjAX. That works to a degree. If I do that how do I increase the distance between the two elements, the distance from the top of the screen and right margin of the page?

Comment: These 2 `id="Icontext";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using simply `display:inline-block` to both element or you can use `display: flex`. for spacing between element you can use `margin` or `padding`

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 margin: 20px; /* spacing to screen*/
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-container div:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px; /* for spaceing between element */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div id="Icontext">Login</div>
<div id="Carttext">Cart</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has got me very close to solving the issue. I have the distance from the top of the page sorted and the distance between the elements. Now how do I adjust the distance from the far right of the page? I really appreciate your help. Is there any way for me to share an image on here? Also by doing it this way my menu bar height has got bigger. I assume I need to adjust the size of the container somehow?

Comment: you can add an image to the question. @FrancisDuggan

Comment: added. you can see where the two pieces of text are now sitting in comparison to their icons

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm pretty much there! Only thing is-if you change the zoom on the web page to less than 50% then the text starts to move. Really not a big deal but is there a small adjustment that might rectify this

Comment: sorry, @FrancisDuggan I am not sure about this. but you can use the media query for that

Comment: @FrancisDuggan I am only tell about this issue after show your full code.

Comment: if this answer solve your problem then please accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following css:

```
#Icontext, #Carttext{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kind of thing that @mplungjan is suggesting with `display: inline-block;` which is probably preferable than using `float: left;`.

Also note that I removed the `;` between the ID and style references.  It's also probably best to be doing these style changes in CSS as shown below.

You can add `margin: 10px;` to add space between them and above them.

```css
.links {
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Icontext" class="links">Login</div>
                 
<div id="Carttext" class="links">Cart</div>
```

Comment: I've added inline-block before which does put them next to each other but then I run into the problem of how I adjust the positon of each element so that they're reponsive to browser adjustment. Both elements are now too high up on my screen and there's not enough distance between them

Comment: You can do that with `margin: 10px` (or whatever distance you want) as shown in my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using **Flexbox**. You can adjust the space between the items with `margin-right`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#Icontext {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="Icontext">Login</div>
  <div id="Carttext">Cart</div>
</div>
```